# RegEx - Need help: get Price tag html

Tags: regex

```
market_listing_price market_listing_price_with_fee\">\r\n\t\t\t\t\t&#36;5.84 USD
```

Want take number 5.84

sure "market_listing_price_with_fee" before this number

Can you help me, thank alot :) iam new RegEx

Comment: What have you tried so far? You should also post your own approach so far, that makes it easier to see where your problems are exactly.

Comment: Is that your actual string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is your actual string that you want to extract data from, you can use;

```
(?<=market_listing_price_with_fee\\">\\r\\n\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t&#36;)(\d+(\.\d{1,2})?)
```

Your price tag will be `$1`

[<kbd>**`Regex101 Link`**</kbd>](http://regex101.com/r/sS6cI7/3)